# Find a unique vector $y$ such that $g(x)=<x,y> $ for all $x \in V$ (Riesz Representation Theorem example)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

Consider $g : M (R)_{2x2}$ → $R$ given by $g(A)=a_{11} + 2a_{12} + 3a_{32} +4a_{22}$. We consider on $M_{2x2} (R)$ the inner product given by $<A,B> = tr(A^t ,B)$. Find the vector $y$.

I only could get the orthonormal basis (obviously), but I don't know exactly where to go from there. Should I simply apply $\sum$ $\overline{g(e_i)}$ $e_i$? I'm having trouble figuring out the computation method.

This is the orthonormal basis:

Let β = 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

Answer (score 2):

In your case the 'vector' $y$ is the matrix $B$ in the vectorspace $M_{2\times 2}(R)$. Assume the matrices are given by
$$
A= \left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) , \quad B = \left(\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right),
$$

then the scalar product is given by
\begin{align}
\langle A, B\rangle &= \text{tr} (A^t B ) = \text{tr}\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} \\
a_{12} & a_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{matrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) = \text{tr} \left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{21}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{21}b_{22} \\
a_{12}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21} & a_{12}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}
\end{matrix}\right) \\ &= a_{11}b_{11}+a_{21}b_{21} + a_{12}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22} \stackrel{!}{=} g(A),
\end{align}
so if $g(A)=a_{11}+2 a_{12}+3 a_{21} + 4 a_{22}$, then the matrix you search is
$$
B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{matrix}\right) .
$$